# Looking for a family of S-shaped functions I could use to adjust marks to an exam.

Tags: functions

I’m looking for a family of functions that I could use to adjust the marks to an exam, when the average or standard deviations are not acceptable.

The functions should be defined on $[0,1]$ (for “reduced” marks). They should be continuous and strictly increasing. They should have $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.

It would be nice if the functions within the family could be (continuously) defined by two or three real parameters, so I have only few degrees of freedom when looking for the “best”  one to adjust the marks.

Ideally, the family should be a group, using function composition, so I could readjust the marks like I adjusted them the first time or revert the adjustment.

Is there any well-known family of functions that would respect this?

PS: Sorry if I am not very accurate, I was taught mathematics many years ago, and in French, so I may be failing to use the right words in English.

Comment: Maybe $f(x)=x^a$.

Comment: Thanks @Eric for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I already considered this family and it does not work for me, as it does not (generally) allow to increase the standard deviation.

Comment: Well, if your points are clustered near 0 or 1 it can help spread them out. 

You might also like this: https://divisbyzero.com/2008/12/22/how-to-curve-an-exam-and-assign-grades/

Comment: You could also consider applying $(2x-1)$, applying $sgn(x)*|x|^a$ and then applying $(x+1)/2$ as a family of functions which do better at modifying std. you can do this in conjunction with $x^a$ which mainly moves the mean. Unfortunately, I don’t think the conjunction has a clear parametrization/group closure.